# How to solve "Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename fonts/codicon.ttf" when using MonacoEditor component with Quasar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, quasar-framework

In a Quasar Framework project I have the following in the quasar.conf.js (similar to how it's described in [this readme here](https://github.com/egoist/vue-monaco#use-esm-version-with-webpack)):

```
const MonacoEditorPlugin = require("monaco-editor-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = function (/* ctx */) {
  return {
build: {
      chainWebpack(chain) {
        chain
          .plugin("monaco-editor-webpack-plugin")
          .use(MonacoEditorPlugin);
      },
[...]
```

In Index.vue I have:

```
import MonacoEditor from 'vue-monaco';

export default {
  components: {
    MonacoEditor,
[...]
```

This used to work with Quasar Framework v1 but doesn't anymore with v2.

I get the following error when trying to run the app as Electron app (`quasar dev -m electron -- --no-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox`):

`Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename fonts/codicon.ttf`

How to solve this error? If that is the same content could webpack detect that so it's only bundled once? And (if not) should one specify an output path (how)?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, the issue should be fixed by this:

```js
build: {
//...

chainWebpack(chain) {
  chain.module
  .rule('fonts')
  .use('url-loader')
  .tap((options) => {
  options.name = `fonts/[path][name][hash:8].[ext]`
  return options
  })
},

//...
}
```

If [this PR](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/pull/11711) get's merged and released though, you shouldn't need the workaround.